# Woocommerce show parent category next to product name on category page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories

We have our product categories set up as follow:

main category 1
-sub category 1.1
-sub category 1.2
-sub category 1.3
main category 2
-sub category 2.1
-sub category 2.2
-sub category 2.3
etc.

With the following code i am trying to display the parent category next to the product name on the category page. What happens is that the category name of a product is only shown when a product is placed inside a parent category AND a sub category. Otherwise the name of the parent category isn't being displayed. For example; if product 'A' has been placed inside parent category 1, there's no category name visible. If i also place the product inside sub category 1.3, the parent category is visible. How to solve this?

```
//remove the Default Title and call another function which will show your own title in place
remove_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_title',10);
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','fun',10);
function fun()
{
    
    global $product;

// If the WC_product Object is not defined globally
if ( ! is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
}
    
        //get product category  
       $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );

    if ( $product_cats && ! is_wp_error ( $product_cats ) ){

        //$single_cat = array_shift( $product_cats ); 
        ?>

        <!--<h2 itemprop="name" class="product_category_title"><span class="product_category"><?php //echo $single_cat->name; ?></span> |  <?php //echo $product->get_name();?></h2>!-->
        <h2 itemprop="name" class="product_category_title"><span class="product_category"><?php echo $product_cats[1]->name; ?></span> |  <?php echo $product->get_name();?></h2>



<?php }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with this line

```
<h2 itemprop="name" class="product_category_title"><span class="product_category"><?php echo $product_cats[1]->name; ?></span> |  <?php echo $product->get_name();?></h2>
```

you are using the second item in the array to display the name and when there is a subcategory this will be an array. And the categories in the array are not necessarily in order of parent subcategory. So you need to loop through the result of $product_cats and determine which one is the parent before printing

```
//remove the Default Title and call another function which will show your own title in place
remove_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_title',10);
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','fun',10);
function fun()
{
    
    global $product;

    // If the WC_product Object is not defined globally
    if ( ! is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
    }
    
    //get product category  
    $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );

    if ( $product_cats && ! is_wp_error ( $product_cats ) ){
        
        foreach ( $product_cats as $product_cat ) {
            if ( $product_cat->parent == 0 ) {
        ?>

                <h2 itemprop="name" class="product_category_title"><span class="product_category"><?php echo $product_cat->name; ?></span> |  <?php echo $product->get_name();?></h2>
        <?php   
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes that you will only ever have 1 main category assigned to a product